# Run Symfony2 console command from the web browser

Tags: symfony

I have to work with a production server that sucks. I can use Symfony2 required PHP version through apache, but not in the CLI, which uses an older PHP version.

So my question is... is there any way I could run console commands from the web browser? So, moving the `console` file to the server root directory and doing some changes... Later, for security reasons, of course, this file would be stored outside the root.

Comment: Maybe with [`exec()`](http://nl3.php.net/exec)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @WouterJ. I tried this, but it uses the CLI PHP. Of course, because `exec` executes a command in CLI :)

Comment: My apologizes... I'm living the same :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a bundle for the console in the browser.

https://github.com/winzou/ConsoleBundle

It is used for shared servers.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to clear the cache from the browser, the whole ConsoleBundle (see accepted answer above) was too much for me (and still too nerdy for my users). I figured out that you can easily use this bundle without the user interface it provides.

```
// install the bundle & run this code, e.g. in a controller
$console = new \CoreSphere\ConsoleBundle\Executer\CommandExecuter($this->container->get('kernel'));
$response = $console->execute("cache:clear --env=prod");
var_dump($response); // returns output and error code etc
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently tried to install the ConsoleBundle mentoined above but composer said it's abandoned. Instead of that use this: https://github.com/CoreSphere/ConsoleBundle

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I know but you should just use the php version which is used by Apache! Either setup an alias in your .bash_profile / .zshrc:
    alias php='/path/to/php/used/by/apache/bin/php'
or always run app/console with the entire path to php
    /path/to/php/used/by/apache/bin/php app/console

Or if the configuration/php.ini is the problem find out which one is used:
    php -i | grep php.ini
Result:
    Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini" for example
You can use a different config file with the --php-ini or -c parameter:
    php -c /etc/php5/cgi -i | grep php.ini

Comment: Thanks, it should work, the problem is that I'm in a jailed shell and can't access apache php binary

Answer (score 1):

A more simple solution for running a command:

```
<pre>
<?php

$output = $return_var= null;
$command = __DIR__.'/../app/console -v cache:clear -e=prod';
echo "Running: $command\n";
exec($command, $output, $return_var);

if (!empty($output) && is_array($output)) {
    echo "Output:\n";
    foreach ($output as $line) {
        echo $line."\n";
    }
} else {
    echo 'Cache could not be cleared: '.var_export($return_var, true);
}
```

Adapted from https://github.com/jerome-fix/symfony-cmf-standard-with-sonata/blob/master/web/reload-fixtures.php

Answer (score 0):

I put up a customised solution to this issue.

After a whole morning of pain and a desperate trying to find a good solution, below the answer to your question.

1) Create a file *.bat* into the web dir like here:

`your_symfony_dir/www/web/console.bat`

This is the file *console.bat* content:

```
set cmd=%~1
cd ..
php app/console %cmd%
```

2) Create a file *.php* into the web dir like here:

`your_symfony_dir/www/web/console.php`

This is the file *console.php* content:

```
<?php
if (!preg_match('/^192\.168\.(1)\.[0-9]+$/', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    die("Access Denied!");
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Console</title>
    </head>
    <body style='font-family: monospace;'>
        <h1>Console</h1>
        <form method='POST'>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Comandi base</legend>               
                <p><button name='pre_cmd[]' value='cache:clear'>Clear Cache</button></p>
                <p><button name='pre_cmd[]' value='assets:install'>Install Assets</button></p>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Comando personalizzato</legend>             
                <p>php app/console <input type='text' name='cmd' value='' /><input type='submit' value='Esegui' name='submit' /> <input type='reset' value='Annulla' /></p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <?php
        if ($_POST) {
            $cmd = $_POST['cmd'] ? $_POST['cmd'] : (is_array($_POST['pre_cmd']) ? $_POST['pre_cmd'][0] : false);
            if ($cmd) {
                echo "<div style='color:white;background:black;padding:10px'>";
                echo "<pre>";
                $output = array();
                exec($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '\console.bat "' . $cmd . '"', $output);
                foreach ($output as $o) {
                    echo htmlspecialchars($o);
                    echo PHP_EOL;
                }
                echo "</pre>";
                echo "</div>";
            } else {
                echo "<p>Comando vuoto</p>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where summary, i get the post values (the command-line input e.g. "cache:clear") and i execut it into the *.bat* file through the command:

```
exec($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '\console.bat "' . $cmd . '"', $output);
```

3)
When you'll execute the url *www.tuodominio.it/console.php* you'll see the form where you can input your command (like cache:clear).
For my comfort, into the bat file i have already set up the "app/console" part, so i have to digit just "cache:clear" or "assets:install", etc

Comment: Hi Roberto, I know it's been a while since this was posted, would you be so kind and help me out with creating linux version of console.bat?